# Heap dump's total size more than the used heap/perm gem

Tags: java, jvm, visualvm, heap-dump

I'm analyzing the memory usage of this tool using VisualVM + VisualGC. I noticed something I wasn't expecting which probably exposes a misunderstanding of mine concerning the JVM and heap dumps.

To give full context, the application I am profiling does a lookup of a huge blob of serialized that which I am then printing the size of using [jamm](https://github.com/jbellis/jamm). After that, the app just sits there and waits until aborted.

Using VisualVM, I see the heap usage growing as expected. Once the operation is complete and the app is just sitting there sleeping, I trigger a GC (or rather, multiple GCs, I get carried away clicking the button) using VisualVM.

- The used heap at that point is **`1,849,825,472 bytes`** and the PermGem used space is `25,864,448 bytes`.
- At which point, I perform a heap dump which obviously takes a while but, when the heap dump completes, the used heap is still just `1,944,542,296 bytes` with the PermGen roughly the same at `25,892,800 bytes`.
- Here's the punch: the heap dump shows a total bytes count of **`2,299,816,089`**.

What could explain such a discrepancy? I repeated the experiments a few times and I'm always getting the same results.

Comment: have you tried opening it with [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) just to see what byte count does it show?